# Need Expert Advice for using sklearn pipeline to create a composite estimator with multiple models & features. Column Transformer with Mixed Types

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, ensemble-modeling

I am trying to use sklearn pipeline to create a composite estimator. Please check attached image for model blueprint. Can anyone help me understand how this can be done in python.

Column Transformer with Mixed Types

Dataset has only 3 columns including target. [featur_1: categorical, feature_2: text, target]

[image: Model Blueprint]

Code (that didn't work!!)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline




# Split the data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['description'], df['reject'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Separate transformers for text and categorical data
text_transformer = TfidfVectorizer()
categorical_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()

# Create a FeatureUnion for combining the outputs of different transformers
combined_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('text', text_transformer, 'description'),
    ('categorical', categorical_transformer, [['reject']])
])

# Create an instance of the SGDClassifier
sgd_classifier = SGDClassifier()

# Create a pipeline for the model
model_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', combined_features),
    ('sgd', sgd_classifier),  # Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier
    ('lgbm', LGBMClassifier())  # LightGBM Classifier
])

# Fit the pipeline on the training data
model_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict on the test data
predictions = model_pipeline.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the accuracy
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy}')
```

- 

```
Error:
"name": "TypeError",
"message": "All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'SGDClassifier()' (type <class 'sklearn.linear_model._stochastic_gradient.SGDClassifier'>) doesn't",
```

- 

Comment: Have you looked at the scikit-learn documentation? It has [a full example on how to work with mixed types data types](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html).

Comment: Yes, I checked. I am stuck because in documentation there is no example to two models together. Also in this blueprint sgd classifier gets text data and its output along with ordinally encoded categorical data goes to Light GBM. I am having trouble replicating it. Can you try